# Laravel 4: Many to Many with extra relationship

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel-4, eloquent

I've got a problem with Laravel 4 and "many to many" query relationship. 
I've got four tables:

1. users
2. needs
3. currency
4. user_needs

User_Needs contains the "many to many" relationships between Users and Needs. describe as follow

```
id - user_id - need_id - currency_id - price
```

ID is an Autoincrement, PK and so on... user_id is the FK for Users table, need_id is the FK for Needs table and currency_id is the FK for Currency table of course. Price is a float.

Inside Laravel 4 Models folder I've created the following Models

**User** with a function for the belongsToMany inside the Model class file:

```
public function needs()
{
return $this->belongsToMany('Need','user_needs','user_id','need_id')->withPivot('price');
}
```

**Need** with a function for the belongsToMany

```
public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('User','user_needs','user_id','need_id')->withPivot('price');
}
```

Everything works fine if I use only those two models, the problem is that I've to add the "currency_id" because every users can set a currency for every needs, I don't know how to update my Models to do it. At the moment my currency model doesn't have a BelongsToMany at the moment because I don't know how to implement it.

Laravel Documentation avoid the topic of "How to Join 3 tables with Many to Many" it's a bit annoying ...

EDIT: If possible to find a solution without an *Intermediate model* like UserNeeds it would be grate

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had a situation like this when trying to assign a Role to a User/Project relationship.

Your currency_id should just be another column in the user_needs pivot table, since is a property of the relationship.  (As you have it).

Use the currency_id column in the user_needs table, update your "withPivot"s to include currency_id, and you will have all of the data you need when querying for the user-need relationship.

EDIT:  You could also do the Currency belongsToMany Users relationship by using the same user_needs table and specifying everything when defining the relationship.

```
// in currency model

return $this->belongsToMany('User', 'user_needs', 'user_id', 'currency_id');
```